# I am looking for more options / information for the HTML attribute: "contenteditable = 'true'" and the javascript: "focus()" function

Tags: javascript, focus, contenteditable

I would like to learn more about the "HTML contenteditable =' true '" attribute and the javascript focus () function.
For example, I would like to know how I can influence the position of the focused line or how to edit the background of a focused line.
I have already googled some things but I can't find the right information.

Does anyone have a good tip?

Comment: More than what? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable

Answer (score 0):

You can check which element is on focus by writing in the Google Chrome console:

```
document.activeElement
```

The contenteditable attribute specifies whether the content of an element is editable or not.

If you want to trigger the focus on a contenteditable element you can do it by:

```
$(".contenteditableClassName").focus();
```

Any other background change on this element is done by CSS for example you can use

```
    .no-touchevents &:hover, &:focus, &:active {
        border-color: white;
        color: blue;
```

You can apply different changes on the element on focus this way.

Also you can remove the focus border on click by using:

```
        .pointer-focus &:focus {
        outline: none;
        }
```